# Why is my apex ALIAS record not updating?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dns-record

I registered my Cloudfront endpoint as an apex ALIAS for my website (TTL:10800). It has been working perfectly for months. Thi ALIAS record is managed by Gandi.net.

I want to update my ALIAS record with another Cloudfront endpoint proxying a new version of the website.

I did update it yesterday, and nothing changed. I assumed that ALIAS records should be instantly updated. To make sure of that, I tried to delete then recreate it: when deleted, the website was indeed instantly offline, when recreated with the new Cloudfront url, it went back online but using the old Cloudfront endpoint.

Why does it not update the endpoint?

In case it could be related, here are a few things about my DNS records:

- I have no A or AAA record
- I have a bunch of CNAME and TXT records that I added for Google and amazon ACM and SES (DKIM) verifications

Except this, I only have the MX record provided by the registar for the webmail.

I would put my 100 rep as a bounty immediately if I could as it is spoiling my long awaited days off work.

Comment: Just to get it clarified, is this question about Route53?

Comment: No I use Gandi.net as registar. I just assumed that updating the alias record would reroute the traffic to the new Cloudfront and wondering why it's not.

Comment: And Gandi provide this ALIAS functionality?

Comment: (It doesn't really matter who is the registrar, I was wondering about which nameservers are used)

Comment: yes they do. I created and used a DNS record as follows  `@ 1800 IN ALIAS XXXXXX.cloudfront.net.` for a few months now

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is that ALIAS is not a DNS record type or feature, rather a service provider specific "behind the scenes" kind of thing that some service providers implement (in different ways). So it may be very important who the service provider is. (I was thinking you were using Route53, but apparently not?)

Comment: Yes, there is no Route53 in the mix. Gandi.net is providing the ALIAS service and Cloudfront takes it from there.

Comment: Ok, good to have that clarified. Maybe add that information to the question, so that it's clear for everyone that it's a question about ALIAS in Gandi's DNS service.

Comment: Just to double check since I have your attention @HåkanLindqvist: if I only have a cloudfront URL to my website, for the apex DNS record I *have to* use an ALIAS record right?

Comment: It's not possible to have a CNAME at the apex (because there are other records), and I don't think that AWS gives you IP addresses to use for your Cloudfront endpoint, so I think your only option are something like ALIAS or not having cloudfront at the apex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and confirming this. I opened a ticket with Gandi support. I also tried to delete and wait for 10mn before recreating the ALIAS but no luck.